# Recursive MergeSort using LinkedList

Tags: c++, mergesort

**Please help me understand how s and f are getting random values and code is behaving this way.**

*Following is my code for MergeSort :*
    [image]

**Problem**

My linked list orginally have following values in the following order:
6 2 53 1 3 5 30 100

When I cout the values of cut, f ,s 
it gives following:

[image]

and after last value of s, it says stopped working as if a segmentation fault has occured.

**Question:**
I do not understand that how s and f are getting random values and code is behaving this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need the following line at the end of your else block:

```
return merged;
```